# Swift OAuth2 p2

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0

I've been trying for a while to get oauth2 to work with Untappd api (https://untappd.com/api/docs#authentication) and have been running into dead ends with a few different oauth2 frameworks.

I've been trying P2 OAuth.  I seem to be able to kick off the auth process, user signs in, I get a code back and run into trouble sending that code back to untappd for a token.  I've been going off of the example from P2 oauth:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

fileprivate var alamofireManager: SessionManager?

var loader: OAuth2DataLoader?

var oauth2 = OAuth2CodeGrantNoTokenType(settings: [
    "client_id": "A0******************",
    "client_secret": "BA******************",
    "authorize_uri": "https://untappd.com/oauth/authenticate",
    "token_uri": "https://untappd.com/oauth/authorize",   
    "redirect_uris": ["****://oauthcallback"], 
    "response_type": "code",
    "secret_in_body": false,
    "keychain": true,
] as OAuth2JSON)

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet var signInEmbeddedButton: UIButton?
@IBOutlet var signInSafariButton: UIButton?
@IBOutlet var signInAutoButton: UIButton?
@IBOutlet var forgetButton: UIButton?


@IBAction func signInEmbedded(_ sender: UIButton?) {
    if oauth2.isAuthorizing {
        oauth2.abortAuthorization()
        return
    }

    sender?.setTitle("Authorizing...", for: UIControlState.normal)

    oauth2.authConfig.authorizeEmbedded = true
    oauth2.authConfig.authorizeContext = self
    oauth2.verbose = true

    oauth2.authorize() { authParameters, error in
        if let params = authParameters {
            print("Authorized! Access token is in `oauth2.accessToken`")
            print("Authorized! Additional parameters: \(params)")
        }
        else {
            print("Authorization was cancelled or went wrong: \(error)")   // error will not be nil
        }
    }

}
```

In the logs I seem to get back the code but the final exchange fails:

> [Debug] OAuth2: Exchanging code 2010D2*********** for access token at https://untappd.com/oauth/authorize
>   redirecting
>
> [Debug] OAuth2: Did exchange code for access [false] and refresh [false] tokens
>   Authorized! Access token is in `oauth2.accessToken`
>   Authorized! Additional parameters: ["meta": {
>       "error_detail" = "Missing either the client_id, redirect_url, client_secret or code parameter. Please check your request a try again.";
>       "error_type" = "param_error";
>       "http_code" = 500;
>   }, "response": <__NSArray0 0x174005900>(
>   )
>   ]

There doesn't seem to be much help for OAuth2 and Swift 3, unless I'm looking in the wrong places.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out.  In case anyone else runs into this.  Turns out just had to modify the OAuth2CodeGrant class to add in the client_secret that wasn't being passed during the code exchange for token:

```
open func accessTokenRequest(with code: String, params: OAuth2StringDict? = nil) throws -> OAuth2AuthRequest {
    guard let clientId = clientConfig.clientId, !clientId.isEmpty else {
        throw OAuth2Error.noClientId
    }
    guard let redirect = context.redirectURL else {
        throw OAuth2Error.noRedirectURL
    }

    guard let clientSecret = clientConfig.clientSecret else {
        throw OAuth2Error.noClientSecret
    }

    let req = OAuth2AuthRequest(url: (clientConfig.tokenURL ?? clientConfig.authorizeURL), method: .GET)

    req.params["code"] = code
    req.params["grant_type"] = type(of: self).grantType
    req.params["redirect_uri"] = redirect
    req.params["client_id"] = clientId
    req.params["client_secret"] = clientSecret

    return req
}
```